# Calculated fields based on another value SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, azure-sql-database

I have a table in an Azure SQL server in which I have a value and a date.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[example] (
  [Value] varchar(50) NULL,
  [Date] date NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[example] ([Value], [Date]) VALUES (N'A', N'2020-04-01')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[example] ([Value], [Date]) VALUES (N'A', N'2020-04-01')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[example] ([Value], [Date]) VALUES (N'B', N'2020-04-03')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[example] ([Value], [Date]) VALUES (N'C', N'2020-04-03')
GO
```

I only have limited experience with MySQL and have difficulties with the altered statements.
within this database I need to calculate a new date based on the value.

I know how to do the Dateadd with the below statement.

```
SELECT
    example.[Value],
    example.[Date], 
    DATEADD(day, 10, example.[Date]) AS NewDate
FROM
    dbo.example
```

but it will add the date to all. I've read about the if else statement but that's where I am failing to get to the result.

what I need is it should only add 10 days IF the Value is in (B, C) Else add 20 days to the current date field. How do I set the If statement to work for every line, because if I use the logic behind this it returns more than one results and it will fail to work

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a if and only if statement in SQL Server.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_iif.asp

It would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    example.[Value],
    example.[Date], 
    IIF(Value IN ('B','C'), DATEADD(day, 10, example.[Date]), DATEADD(day, 20, example.[Date])) AS NewDate
FROM
    dbo.example
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpfull. Looks like I was messing up the brackets

Comment: @Herr_Bruder did you get the answer working? I see in your previous post you were getting a syntax error. Can you show me your query? Pay extra attention to the required comma's and parenthesis as your error message is stating you have the incorrect amount. `IIF(CONDITION,[IF TRUE], [IF FALSE])`

Comment: Yes I did, your example worked. I believe I initially wrote something like "IIF Value IN..." without the brackets for the IIF function. a rookie mistake.
The CASE function generated an error for me. I have that method working as well now but with using the OR function instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement in most SQL dialects:

```
    SELECT
        example.[Value],
        example.[Date], 
    CASE WHEN example.[Value] IN ('B', 'C'), 
         THEN DATEADD(day, 10, example.[Date])
         ELSE DATEADD(day, 20, example.[Date])
         END AS NewDate 
    FROM
        dbo.example
```

Comment: I tried both your and Jerrit's answer, this one gives an error.
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. (102)